# Unusual results in PowerShell for loop

Tags: powershell, active-directory

I have the following module.

I've obsfucated the hashtable to protect sensitive information, but it has a bunch of values that define a domain controller, DN of the domain, domain specific username etc:

```
function set-domparams {
    Param(
        [Parameter(Mandatory = $true,Position=0)]
        [string]$domain,
        [Parameter(Mandatory = $true,Position=1)]
        [string[]]$username,
        [Alias("pass","p")]
        [Parameter(Mandatory = $false,Position=2)]
        $password,
        [Parameter(Mandatory = $true,Position=3)]
        [ValidateSet("Y","N")]
        [string]$cyberArk
    )

    Invoke-Expression -Command:'cmd.exe /c klist purge' | Out-Null

    function Get-Creds($domain,$user,$password) {
        if (!($password)) {$password = Read-Host "Enter $domain password" -AsSecureString}
        Invoke-Expression -Command:'cmd.exe /c klist purge' | Out-Null
        $creds = New-Object -TypeName System.Management.Automation.PSCredential -ArgumentList $username,$password
        return $creds
    }

    $doms = @{
        'domain1.com' = @{'serverDC' = "somesvalidDC.fqdn.com";'searchBase' = "DC=somesvalidDC,DC=fqdn,DC=com";'suffix' = "domain1.com"; 'TSMserver' = "127.0.0.1"; 'NetBIOS' = "domain1"; 'SCOM' = "somescomserver.com";'AdminSuffix' = "_admin"}
        'domain2.com' = @{'serverDC' = "somesvalidDC.fqdn.com";'searchBase' = "DC=somesvalidDC,DC=fqdn,DC=com";'suffix' = "domain2.com"; 'TSMserver' = "127.0.0.1"; 'NetBIOS' = "domain2"; 'SCOM' = "somescomserver.com";'AdminSuffix' = ".adm"}
    }

    if ((!$cyberArk) -or ($cyberArk -eq 'N')) {
        $global:fetchCreds = Get-Creds -domain $domain -user $username -password $password
    } else {
        $CyberArkUser = "cyberarkdom\" + $username
        $CyberArkdomain = 'cyberarkdom.int'
        $global:fetchCreds = Get-Creds -domain $CyberArkdomain -user $CyberArkUser -password $password
    }

    $global:adminsuffix = $doms.$domain.AdminSuffix
    $global:user = $doms.$domain.NetBIOS + "\" + $username + $adminsuffix
    $global:dc = $doms.$domain.serverDC
    $global:DomNBT = $doms.$domain.NetBIOS
    $global:searchbase = $doms.$domain.searchBase
    $global:suffix = $doms.$domain.suffix
    $global:TSMserver = $doms.$domain.TSMserver
    $global:scom = $doms.$domain.scom
}
```

I have used this numerous times in scripts and it works, but am currently having an odd problem when attempting an operation against multiple domains in a new script:

```
Param(
    [Parameter(Mandatory = $true)]
    [ValidateSet("Y","N")]
    [string]$cyberArk
)

$userprompt = Read-Host "Enter username"
$userpass = Read-Host "Enter $domain password" -AsSecureString

$domainlist = @('domain1.fqdn.co', 'anotherdomain.com', 'differesntforest3.com.au')

foreach ($domain in $domainlist) {
    $results = ""
    set-domparams -domain $domain -username $userprompt -password $userpass -cyberArk $cyberArk

    $results = Get-ADGroup -Server $DC -Credential $fetchCreds -Filter * |
               where {$_.Name -like "*-DelAdmin-Servers*"} |
               select Name, SamAccountName
    foreach ($result in $results) {
        [PSCustomObject]@{
            Name = $result.Name
            domain = $domain
            samaccountname = $result.SamAccountName
        }
    }
}
```

I get the following error when the domain list contains domains across different forests (password is consistent across domains):

```
Get-ADGroup : The server has rejected the client credentials.
At E:\Scripts\get-testrun.ps1:16 char:16
+ ...  $results = Get-ADGroup -Server $DC -Credential $fetchCreds -Filter * ...
+                 ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : SecurityError: (:) [Get-ADGroup], AuthenticationException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : ActiveDirectoryCmdlet:System.Security.Authentication.AuthenticationException,Microsoft.ActiveDirectory.Management.Commands.GetADGroup
```

If run as a one liner against any of these domains individually, the module works and authenticates fine, returning all of the global variables and performing the query in the script without error.

What am I missing?

Comment: Please consider providing an [MCVE (Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example)](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), or as close as you can get to one. There are a lot of distracting elements in your code (liberal use of global variables, needless use of `Invoke-Expression`).

Comment: `$fetchCreds` isn't defined  in the 2nd script...

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in the comments the offending line is your `Get-ADGroup`. Specifically the following:

```
Get-ADGroup -Server $DC -Credential $fetchCreds -Filter *
```

In your second, current script, you don't define `$fetchCreds`. if you do have similar other scripts it's likely that you're either assigning something directly or you're using `$global:fetchCreds` as that's what's being prepared in your first script.

Comment: $fetchcreds is a global variable that is defined after passing the necessary parameters to get-adgroup, and can be seen as a credential object when typing $fetchcreds after running against a single domain as a one liner

Comment: That sounds nonsensical. If it is only defined AFTER passing it to `Get-ADGroup` you won't be able to use it for `Get-ADGroup`. In addition yes, it's defined in the global scope. Did you try to prefix the `$global`? Maybe for some reason your invocation leads to not having that automatic expansion?

Comment: Correction - BEFORE (typo). This works with the same code outside of the for loop against any single given domain, so there's something odd going on I can't make sense of, posting in here in the hope there's something obvious I might be missing.

Comment: Did you have a look at the contents of the globals within the loop? If so, what was the result? Do they contain the expected values? Your `$userpass` prompt contains an undefined variable `$domain`. Also `Get-Creds` is always called and has its own prompt. Do you get `set-domparams` using an `Import-Module` or is it part of the same file? As a side note: You could use your `where` as the filter for the `Get-ADGroup`.

Answer (score 0):

I realized there was an error in the logic of the function I was using.

Once fixed it happily runs against any number of domains (i.e. against an array of a bunch of different arrays).

```
function set-domparams {
Param(
    [Parameter(Mandatory = $true,Position=0)]
    [string]$domain,
    [Parameter(Mandatory = $true,Position=1)]
    [string[]]$username,
    [Alias("pass","p")]
    [Parameter(Mandatory = $false,Position=2)]
    $password,
    [Parameter(Mandatory = $true,Position=3)]
    [ValidateSet("Y","N")]
    [string]$cyberArk
)

function Get-Creds($domain,$user,$password) {
    Invoke-Expression -Command:'cmd.exe /c klist purge' | Out-Null
    If (!($password)) {$password = Read-Host "Enter $domain password" -AsSecureString}
          $creds = new-object -typename System.Management.Automation.PSCredential -argumentlist $user,$password      
          return $creds
    }

$doms = @{
    'domain1.com' = @{'serverDC' = "somesvalidDC.fqdn.com";'searchBase' = "DC=somesvalidDC,DC=fqdn,DC=com";'suffix' = "domain1.com"; 'TSMserver' = "127.0.0.1"; 'NetBIOS' = "domain1"; 'SCOM' = "somescomserver.com";'AdminSuffix' = "_admin"}
    'domain2.com' = @{'serverDC' = "somesvalidDC.fqdn.com";'searchBase' = "DC=somesvalidDC,DC=fqdn,DC=com";'suffix' = "domain2.com"; 'TSMserver' = "127.0.0.1"; 'NetBIOS' = "domain2"; 'SCOM' = "somescomserver.com";'AdminSuffix' = ".adm"}
}

$global:adminsuffix = $doms.$domain.AdminSuffix
$global:dc = $doms.$domain.serverDC
$global:DomNBT = $doms.$domain.NetBIOS
$global:searchbase = $doms.$domain.searchBase
$global:suffix = $doms.$domain.suffix
$global:TSMserver = $doms.$domain.TSMserver
$global:scom = $doms.$domain.scom

If ((!$cyberArk) -or ($cyberArk -eq 'N')) {

    $global:user = $doms.$domain.NetBIOS + "\" + $username + $adminsuffix
    $global:fetchCreds = Get-Creds -domain $domain -user $user -password $password

}

Else {

    $global:User = "corpau\" + $username 
    $CyberArkdomain = 'corpau.wbcau.westpac.com.au'
    $global:fetchCreds = Get-Creds -domain $CyberArkdomain -user $user -password $password

}
```

}

Certainly not the best written function by any means, but does the job it was designed to do.